# Code doesn't work when implementing inheritance in Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

While studying the basics inheritance in Java, I came across an exercise that seems pretty simple, but I don't know exactly where I'm going wrong since I'm not getting an error message, the program just doesn't start - actually, it executes another program, always the one I built and ran just before this one. About the exercise I'm working on, I'm supposed to build 3 classes:

- One is the class Animal, which is a superclass, and has as its methods the acts of eat and sleep;
- The other 2 are the classes Cat and Bird.
- All animals eat and sleep, but only cats have fur, and only birds have feathers.

All I have to do is build the classes structure using inheritance, and all methods must print their own name when called. The method eat must be visible only within the package (which I assumed it meant it was protected), and the method sleep must be visible only within the classes of the hierarchy, and can't be extended, which I assumed it meant it was final.

This is what I have done:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
        
        class Animal {
            
            protected void eat() {
                System.out.println("eat");
            }
            
            final void sleep() {
                System.out.println("sleep");
            }
            
        }
        
        class Cat extends Animal {
            
            void haveFur() {
                System.out.println("haveFur");
            }
            
        }
        
        class Bird extends Animal {

            void haveFeathers() {
                System.out.println("haveFeathers");
            }
            
        }
        
        Bird bird = new Bird();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        bird.eat();
        bird.sleep();
        bird.haveFeathers();
        cat.eat();
        cat.sleep();
        cat.haveFur();
        
    }
```

Whenever I run the code, it always runs the latest build I did, and never this program itself. Also, if I take out the last part (from Bird bird = new Bird(); to cat.haveFur();), it runs, but shows nothing, as none of the classes has been called. So, I understand the problem might be on the last part, but I'm not sure where. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Whenever I run the code, it always runs the latest build I did` You'll have to describe how you are starting / running the code.  Your problem obviously has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE, and I just press the "run" button and verify if it's running the right package. I noticed now that the package of this exercise isn't even showing in the "save and launch" list. Do you happen to know why does this happen?

Comment: Also, if I erase that last part, it's shown on the list, and it runs but obviously shows nothing. I want to have an output, but now I don't know how

Comment: In a different IDE, when I press the "run" button it depends on which project or file I have selected.  So you might be running the wrong project or some other code.  Try running the file directly by select "Run File" or something similar by right clicking on the file or project.

Comment: The code is working, it's just a problem with your IDE maybe some project errors. If you want to really make sure, make a new clean project and put that code in

Comment: @AndréClérigo it worked! Thank you so much, I don't know why it happened. Thanks!

Comment: @markspace and thanks to you too for helping me, I really was running the wrong project